# Kotlin instantiate open class with primary construction

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a simple scenario in which I have bank accounts from multiple countries. Some information is basic, and each country may have their own particularities. Therefore, I created an open class called `DefaultBankAccount` and I can have country-specific classes inherit them. However, I am not being able to instantiate a simple `DefaultBankAccount` object.

When I do, the properties in the constructor are empty:

```
@Document(collection = "bankAccount")
open class DefaultBankAccount(
    accountNumber: String,
    address: String,
    bankName: String,
    codeIban: String,
    codeSwift: String,
    country: String,
    holderName: String
) {
    companion object {
        @Transient
        val SEQUENCE_NAME = "payments_sequence"
    }

    @Id
    var id: Long = 0
    var createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
    var updatedAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
}
```

Using the primary constructor, the result is:

[image]

So none of the properties on the primary constructor are initialized. However, if I instantiate a class that inherits from DefaultBankAccount, it seems fine:

```
@Document(collection = "bankAccount")
data class BrazilBankAccount(
    val accountNumber: String,
    val address: String,
    val bankName: String,
    val codeIban: String,
    val codeSwift: String,
    val country: String,
    val holderName: String,
    val bankCode: String,
    val branch: String,
    val digit: String,
    val type: String,
    val ispb: String,
    val docType: String,
    val docNumber: String
) : DefaultBankAccount(accountNumber, address, bankName, codeIban, codeSwift, country, holderName) {
    companion object {
        @Transient
        val SEQUENCE_NAME = "payments_sequence"
    }
}
```

[image]

**My question is**: how do I make it so that I can instantiate a DefaultBankAccount object with all its properties?

Comment: Did you really use the primary constructer of the DefaultBankAccount? It seems doubtful that those properties weren't initialized... can you provide code using primary contructor?

Comment: `DefaultBankAccount` has only 3 properties, others has no `val` or `var` keyword so they are just constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the properties in the constructor are empty

There are no properties declared in the constructor of `DefaultBankAccount`, because there is no `val` or `var` keyword in front of those parameter declarations. In the current state of things, those constructor parameters are useless, because they are not used anywhere in the class body.

In the child class `BrazilBankAccount`, the constructor parameters all have the `val` keyword in front, which makes them properties.

If you need `DefaultBankAccount` to have those properties too, add a `val` keyword in front of each of them. Note that you'll need an `override` modifier on all the child class's constructor properties.